# Split a data.frame efficiently

Tags: r, split, dataframe, apply

I have this `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
n=20
df <- data.frame(s1 = paste(sample(0:3, n, replace = TRUE),sample(0:3, n, replace = TRUE),sep="/"),
                  s2 = paste(sample(0:3, n, replace = TRUE),sample(0:3, n, replace = TRUE),sep="/"),
                  s3 = paste(sample(0:3, n, replace = TRUE),sample(0:3, n, replace = TRUE),sep="/"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In reality the number of columns is ~ 1,000 and number of rows is ~1,000,000.

What's an efficient way to split this data.frame into two data.frames by the `"/"` character in each field?

This is one way, using `mclapply`:

```
library(parallel)
split.mat = do.call(rbind,mclapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
  mat = sapply(df[x,1:ncol(df)], function(y) strsplit(y, split = "\\/")[[1]])
  return(c(mat[1,],mat[2,]))
}, mc.core = 10))
```

But I'm wondering whether there's anything more efficient

Comment: What is the chance that you have some genotype data?

Comment: You caught me.. However, it's not a conventional VCF format. It just has the CHROM. POS, and GT fields. Any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Here's something a bit odd:

```
library(data.table)
fwrite(df, sep = "/", quote = FALSE,
       col.names = FALSE, file = "df.txt")

NN <- 2L*ncol(df)

DT1 <- fread("df.txt", sep = "/", select = seq(from = 1L, to = NN, by = 2L))
DT2 <- fread("df.txt", sep = "/", select = seq(from = 2L, to = NN, by = 2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

suggestion: to use stri_split_fixed... some benchmarks shown below...
(code assumes that you read data in as matrix and then you turn it into a character vector, split using '/', then matrix(prevOutput, nrow=origNrow, ncol=2*origNcol)

```
options(stringsAsFactors=F)
library(rbenchmark)
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)
ncols <- 1
nrows <- 10*1000
strdat <- paste(sample(0:3, nrows*ncols, replace=T),
    sample(0:3, nrows*ncols, replace=T), sep="/")

benchmark(strsplitMtd=lapply(strdat, function(x) strsplit(x,"/")[[1]]),
    striMtd=stri_list2matrix(stri_split_fixed(strdat, "/"), byrow=T),
    tidyrMtd=separate(data.frame(S=strdat), S, c("S1","S2"), "/"))
```

pls let me know if you need more or if i offend any SO etiquette